# Mongodb unique index on two keys of an array of objects. Only check unique when fields exist

Tags: mongodb, unique-constraint

Say I have a product collection like this:

```
{
  "_id": "<id>",
  "name": "Product A",
  "vendors": [
    {
      "vendor_id": 1,
      "code": "A"
    },
    {
      "vendor_id": 2,
      "code": "B"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to set unique index on the pair "vendor_id" and "code" of "vendors" only when they exist because "code" is not required.
This is what I did:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
{ "vendors.vendor_id": 1,  "vendors.code": 1}, 
{ 
  unique: true,
  partialFilterExpression: {
    "vendors.vendor_id": { $exists: true },
    "vendors.code": { $exists: true }
  }
})
```

It works with documents like these:

```
{
  "_id": "<id>",
  "name": "Product A",
  "vendors": [
    {
      "vendor_id": 1
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": "<id>",
  "name": "Product B",
  "vendors": [
    {
      "vendor_id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

This does not work when vendor_id and code exist on different elements of vendors.
For example:

```
{
  "_id": "<id>",
  "name": "Product A",
  "vendors": [
    {
      "vendor_id": 1
    },
    {
      "vendor_id": 2,
      "code": "B"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": "<id>",
  "name": "Product B",
  "vendors": [
    {
      "vendor_id": 1
    },
    {
      "vendor_id": 2,
      "code": "C"
    }
  ]
}
```

With my current index, mongodb returns error `duplicate {"vendor_id": 1, "code": null}`.

How to make these 2 documents accepted because `"vendor_id": 1` does not have "code" so it should not be checked duplicate.